# Scroll using jQuery touch events for jfree images

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, touch, jfreechart

I have a chart drawing using jfree charts for ipad.
The chart image is shown in a div.
I have to implement scroll functionlitly for chart.
On Scroll:

- New chart will be generated on server side and shown.

I am doing it using swipe left and swipe right.
I am not able to achieve touch and scroll.
As shown in image.
I tried using touchstart and touch move but then swipe event is not working.
Is there a way to do it?

[image]

In image when touched and scrolled to left.I should be able to identify the touch and scroll different from swipe left and swipe right

Comment: Tell me why do you need a scroll event? What you want to achieve is a swipeleft event and you are already using it.

Answer (score 0):

i have no working example but facing similar problems. A possible solution could be iScrollview (iScroll for JQM) https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview.

See also PINCH/ZOOM: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

```
iScroll - Example: http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/zoom/
```

**Let me know if it worked.**

Comment: I did it using http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/ .By calculating swipe distance.